# Adding a list of strings to an array - new Java user

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

I have this following code;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sequence
{
    // the numbers in the sequence

    private ArrayList<String> list;
    //defining an array called list
    String dwade;

    public Sequence(String s)
    {
        dwade = s;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> conversion()
    {
        for (String retval: dwade.split(",")) {
            list.add(retval)
        }
        return list;           
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to do in the method for conversion is to split the string s and place the split strings into an array.

```
e.g. s = "1,5,7,0"
dwade = "1,5,7,0"
list= ["1", "5", 7", "0"]   <--this is an array/matrix
```

But when i compile this in bluej, i get an error.
Whats an easy way to do this (for beginers)

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You seem to be missing some semi-colons...

Comment: Please don't make us sit here and guess/speculate about what errors you could possibly be getting. **Just post them**.

Comment: If you need an array, then `return dwade.split(",")` instead of adding the result to the ArrayList.

Comment: You need to give us the stacktrace.

Comment: You also need to initialize your list in your constructor, or else you will get a null pointer, assuming the code compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ArrayList<String> conversion() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String retval : dwade.split(",")){
        list.add(retval);
    }
    return list;
}
```